# how to do string bash array minus comparision?

Tags: linux, bash

say I need to skip some apps are in broken/out of sync status before deployment,  so:

out_of_sync_before_deployment = "app1,app2,app3,app4,"

out_of_sync_now = "app2,app5,app4,,"

I want get "app5"  which is removing apps in out_of_sync_before_deployment from out_of_sync_now, how I do this in bash? I can only do this in bash, thx

Comment: Your subject says "array" but your example shows strings (using invalid bash syntax). Which are you trying to compare, arrays or strings?

Comment: maybe first change string to an array, but you see I need compare one app by one app

Comment: do whatever you have to do to make your question consistent and accurate. If you want strings to be your starting point, go with that consistently, if you want arrays to be your starting point then go with that consistently. Either way make sure to provide a [mcve] that includes your code attempt, see [ask].